# Using mvc Jquery How to get selected Radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Mvc Razor Code as

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Myapplication.ApplicationType,new { value="1" })
```

For Getting its Value i had Written as

```
        $("#Myapplication_ApplicationStatusNum").keyup(function (key) {           
            var _Selected = $("#Myapplication_ApplicationType").val();
}
```

Im Getting Output as

```
"{ value = 1 }"
```

Please Help me How can i get only 1

Comment: please read [ask]. I don't see what your question / problem is.

Comment: See the [documentation for the `RadioButtonFor` overload you're using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_InputExtensions_RadioButtonFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Object_). `new { value = "1" }` is the value you are giving the radio button, not the HTML attributes. If you want the value to be "1", pass "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of a radio button in jquery you can do the following:

```
$('#// ID of radioButton').is(':checked');
```

Comment: This does not get the value of the radio button. This gets the value of its `checked` property, a related, but different, property.

Comment: @HereticMonkey My guess is that OP is wanting to check the value of whether or not the radio button is checked or not. Which is why I'm guessing they are setting it to 1

Comment: Why guess? Ask (using a comment). Then answer based on the response.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Well based on the variable OP is trying to assign the value to `_Selected`, the logical thing to think is that they are wanting to see whether or not the radio button is selected